# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on presentRenderbuffer

Tags: objective-c, ios7, rendering, opengl-es-2.0

When I call `presentRenderBuffer` in some situations my app crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. But usually all is ok.

Call stack is here:

```
#0  0x2f53f02e in glrGetPrivateInteger ()
#1  0x329a192e in gliGetInteger ()
#2  0x002eec04 in __collect_all_context_profiling_data_block_invoke ()
#3  0x0015ea7c in iter_contexts ()
#4  0x002ee7f2 in collect_all_context_profiling_data ()
#5  0x00163fbc in copy_profiling_data_dictionary(ContextInfo*, unsigned int, unsigned long long) ()
#6  0x00160566 in handle_frame_boundary ()
#7  0x002f194c in EAGLContext_presentRenderbuffer(EAGLContext*, objc_selector*, unsigned int) ()
#8  0x00044a68 in __36-[CanvasView initializeWithContext:]_block_invoke56
```

Do you have any ideas about this?

**SOLVE:**

Texture is created and deleted in different contexts. This has caused problems.

Now texture is created and deleted in one context. It has solved the problem.

Comment: Buffer swap in a thread with no active/valid render context, perhaps?

Comment: Yes. Context is valid.

Comment: It'd be nice to figure out the definitive cause of the problem because my reading of the documentation is that it's valid to create and delete a GL resource in different contexts if they're members of a sharegroup and appropriate `glFlush`es are inserted.